# average grade and grade level calculator

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a calculator that gets the user to input 5 test scores. These test scores will take the average of those scores, and determine a letter grade from those numbers. It should display both the average and the letter grade.

This is my code:

```py
firstTest = 0
secondTest = 0
thirdTest = 0
forthTest = 0
fifthTest = 0
addedTestScores = 0
testScores = 0

def main():
    global testScores
    calc_average()
    determine_grade()

    
def calc_average():
    firstTest = float(input('Enter your first score: '))
    secondTest = float(input('Enter your second score: '))
    thirdTest = float(input('Enter your third score: '))
    forthTest = float(input('Enter your forth score: '))
    fifthTest = float(input('Enter your fifth score: '))

    addedTestScores = firstTest + secondTest + thirdTest + forthTest + fifthTest
    
    testScores = (addedTestScores / 5)

    print ('This is your average: ', testScores)


def determine_grade():

    if testScores <= 100 or testScores >= 90:
        print ('You have an A ')
    elif testScores < 90 or testScores >= 80:
        print ('You have a B')
    elif testScores < 80 or testScores >= 70:
        print ('You have a C')
    elif testScores < 70 or testScores >= 60:
        print ('You have a D')
    else:
        print ('You have an E')

main()
```

My output for the letter grade determination is only "You have an A". I'm not sure why, I thought if I made my variable, `testScores`, a global variable, it would fix my problem, but I'm not sure if I'm putting the global variable in the correct place. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!